# Correct Way To Load An Alternate Version Of jQuery For IE8 And Below

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, conditional-statements, styling, convention

I would like to update the jQuery library on my site, but when I use the newer versions (2+?) certain things stop working when using IE 8 or below.

After reading more than several posts about using alternate versions of jQuery depending on certain conditions, I have a couple questions about the actual implementation - refer to the versions below:

VER1

```
  <![if !IE|gte IE 8]>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]>

  <![if lt IE 9]> //(COMMENTED OUT)
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]>
```

VER2

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <![if lt IE 9]> //(COMMENTED OUT)
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]>
```

First Question: Both versions seem to be work as expected so far. In VER2, will IE8 and below browsers end up loading two versions of jQuery (which as I understand it, can cause issues)?

Second Question: Would VER1 be an acceptable or conventional implementation of what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Side Note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working

Comment: here's one of the posts, but I don't think it addresses weather or not you need to put ALL jQuery versions in conditional statements if you have more than one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251261/conditional-comments-alternative-to-load-jquery

Comment: I think you missed the point of the page I linked.  The point being IE 10 and beyond do not support the conditionals at all.

Comment: does that mean that IE10+ will still be loading 2 different versions of jQuery?  Same for other browsers? I think you're right, I'm missing the point.

Comment: That is accurate.  I verified it in IE 11.

Comment: I just added two scripts containing console.log();s inside of each conditional statement, I ran IE 8,9,10,11 and a new instance of chrome, in each case I only saw one of the console.log()'s, and the output was correct in each case, meaning I never saw both scripts load.  In what case will this allow both to be loaded?

Comment: I took exactly what you have for your VER2 snippet (minus the //COMMENT part), put it in a head on an blank html page, opened IE 11 and recorded the network traffic.  Both the 3.3.1 and 1.7.2 resources were requested.

Comment: ahh, I see what you mean, I'm looking at the same thing and even seeing it on 8 and below. Can you point me in the right direction?  Also, why is this the case when it seemed on the surface to be working with the console.log(); test?

Comment: Others may be able to advise you on this issue.  Personally I would probably error on the side of having a single library version that works with all the browsers you are required to support, OR, if you do include a version that is lacking functionality with older versions of IE that you must be able to support, it's also a possibility to provide shims for the functionality that the older versions are missing so you can keep using just the newer versions of the library.